# Run Angular Test with Karma in inetllij idea

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, karma-jasmine

Getting below error while executing Angular Test with Karma in inetllij idea

```
20 11 2019 12:16:27.838:ERROR [karma]: Error: The '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma' karma plugin is meant to be used from within Angular CLI and will not work correctly outside of it.
    at init (C:\Users\X196360\dev\OCP\ocp-front\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\packages\angular_devkit\build_angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\karma.ts:60:11)
    at Array.invoke (C:\Users\X196360\dev\OCP\ocp-front\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:75:15)
    at Injector.get (C:\Users\X196360\dev\OCP\ocp-front\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:48:43)
    at config.frameworks.forEach (C:\Users\X196360\dev\OCP\ocp-
            ...
            ...
```

Comment: Can you please specify the way you run the tests? Maybe the command you are running or the IDEA configuration window

Comment: What Angular and IDE versions do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Support for running karma tests in Angular CLI 6+ projects is available since IDEA 2018.2.x. If you are using some older IDE version, try downgrading Angular to 5.x. Otherwise, make sure to choose `path/to/node_modules/@angular/cli` as a **Karma package:** in your run configuration, like

[image]